# What causes new spark plugs to burn out quickly on 2005 altima

Tags: nissan, sparkplugs, altima

I just replaced sparks plugs and drove my car estimated five miles and my #1 plugs has burned out and white on tip

Comment: Did you buy the right kind of plugs for it? Meaning, did you purchase low end copper plugs or higher end iridium (or whatever the car calls for)?

Comment: What is the part number and manufacturer for the sparkplug?  What model of Altima do you have?  What is the engine size?

Comment: Does your car burn oil? According to https://www.ngksparkplugs.com/about-ngk/faqs/spark-plug-faqs/how-do-i-read-a-spark-plug the white deposits are affected by oil leakage and fuel quality. Anyway, 5 miles seems short.

Comment: Did you purchase the right plug and it is in good condition.